# diagnosing memory leak in python

Tags: python, memory-leaks, objgraph

I've been trying to debug a memory leak in the Coopr package using objgraph: https://gist.github.com/3855150

I have it pinned down to a `_SetContainer` object, but can't seem to figure out why that object is persisting in memory. Here's the result of `objgraph.show_refs`:

[image: show_refs]

How do I go about finding the circular reference and how can I get the the garbage collector to collect the `_SetContainer` instance?

*I previously thought that the class itself might have a self-reference (the tuple just below the class on the right in the image above). But objgraph always shows inherited classes always as having a self-referencing tuple. You can see a very simple test case [here](https://gist.github.com/3855150#file_inheritance_test.py).*

Comment: [<class 'pyutilib.component.core.core.PluginMeta'>,
 {'__and__': <function __and__ at 0x7928f0>, ...,  'union': <function union at 0x792830>},

 (<class 'coopr.pyomo.base.sets._SetContainer'>,
  <class 'coopr.pyomo.base.sets._BaseSet'>,
  <class 'coopr.pyomo.base.component.Component'>,
  <class 'pyutilib.component.core.core.Plugin'>,
  <type 'object'>),

 (<class 'coopr.pyomo.base.sets._BaseSet'>,),
 <class 'coopr.pyomo.base.sets._BaseSet'>]

Comment: using ``pprint(gc.get_referents(obj.__class__))``. the self-referencing tuple is there, but it's attribute name isn't given.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly guessing from the output of objgraph, but it seems that the instance is in a cycle and its class has a `__del__`.  In this situation, the object is kept alive forever in CPython.  Check it with:

`import gc; gc.collect(); print gc.garbage`

http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage

Comment: ``print gc.garbage`` returns an empty list, but ``count=gc.collect();`` is non-zero. I believe this means that there are uncollectable objects. Also, the [_SetContainer class](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/browser/coopr.pyomo/trunk/coopr/pyomo/base/sets.py) (or the [Component class](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/browser/coopr.pyomo/trunk/coopr/pyomo/base/component.py) it inherits from) doesn't have a ``__del__`` method explicitly defined.

Comment: I take the second statement back - I just found the inherited ``__del__`` method.

Comment: No, gc.collect() returns the number of unreachable object that have been found and collected.  You might be hitting a case where gc.collect() is not run often enough?  (Normally, it runs automatically from time to time.)  Try doing a few calls to gc.collect() explicitly during the runtime of your program...